# Merge duplicate rows, sum time and get average time or sum average time

Tags: mysql, merge, double

it sounds a bit complicated and I am struggling with a query. Hopefully you can help me out.

[image: The current state]

What I need is to merge by name or date, the count and time column should be sum (02:05:00) and aht column should be average of both values.

I didnt found a solution, as all comes up with a group by view, but I need to have the data in one row and the second row deleted...

Comment: Providing text instead of images helps to get faster recommendations from the community

Comment: Please provide an example of sample data and the expected output

Comment: If you are not sure your explanation is great, examples are a great addition to your question. If you show what you are starting with and ALSO what you want the result to produce, we can read between the lines of a question asked in a foreign language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting the SUM and AVERAGE is not hard, see below fiddle:

```
SELECT
   name,
   `date`,
   sum(`count`) as 'count',
   SEC_TO_TIME(sum(TIME_TO_SEC(`time`))) as 'time',
   SEC_TO_TIME(avg(TIME_TO_SEC(aht)))  as aht
FROM table1
GROUP BY
   name,
   `date`;
```

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=171518c9c364400f93cb9232e7aacf79)

output:

| name | date | count | time | aht |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name | 2022-03-28 | 36 | 02:05:00 | 00:03:11.0000 |

You can add this new row, and after this delete all rows that have a  count >=2 when grouped by `name` and `date`.